# Coq `path` implementation

Tags: coq

This is a follow up to [Coq equality implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764368/coq-equality-implementation) (though this question is self-contained).

I have a simple inductive type of trees (`t`) with a fixed set of tags (`arityCode`), each with a fixed number of children. I have a type (`path`) of paths into a tree. I'm trying to implement some manipulations. In particular, I want to be able to move a cursor around in a few directions. This seems pretty straightforward, but I'm running into a roadblock.

This is all in the code, but a quick explanation of where I'm stuck: To construct a `there` path, I need to produce a `path (Vector.nth v i)` (a path in one of the children). But the only `path` constructors (`here` and `there`) produce a `path (Node c v)`. So in some sense I need to show the compiler that a path simultaneously has type `path (Node c v)` and `path (Vector.nth v i)`, but Coq is not clever enough to compute `(Vector.nth children fin_n)` -> `Node c v`. How can I convince it that this is okay?

```
Require Coq.Bool.Bool. Open Scope bool.
Require Coq.Strings.String. Open Scope string_scope.
Require Coq.Arith.EqNat.
Require Coq.Arith.PeanoNat. Open Scope nat_scope.
Require Coq.Arith.Peano_dec.
Require Coq.Lists.List. Open Scope list_scope.
Require Coq.Vectors.Vector. Open Scope vector_scope.
Require Fin.

Module Export LocalVectorNotations.
Notation " [ ] " := (Vector.nil _) (format "[ ]") : vector_scope.
Notation " [ x ; .. ; y ] " := (Vector.cons _ x _ .. (Vector.cons _ y _ (Vector.nil _)) ..) : vector_scope.
Notation " [ x ; y ; .. ; z ] " := (Vector.cons _ x _ (Vector.cons _ y _ .. (Vector.cons _ z _ (Vector.nil _)) ..)) : vector_scope.
End LocalVectorNotations.

Module Core.

    Module Typ.
      Set Implicit Arguments.

      Inductive arityCode : nat -> Type :=
        | Num   : arityCode 0
        | Hole  : arityCode 0
        | Arrow : arityCode 2
        | Sum   : arityCode 2
        .

      Definition codeEq (n1 n2 : nat) (l: arityCode n1) (r: arityCode n2) : bool :=
        match l, r with
          | Num, Num     => true
          | Hole, Hole   => true
          | Arrow, Arrow => true
          | Sum, Sum     => true
          | _, _         => false
        end.

      Inductive t : Type :=
        | Node : forall n, arityCode n -> Vector.t t n -> t.

      Inductive path : t -> Type :=
        | Here  : forall n (c : arityCode n) (v : Vector.t t n), path (Node c v)
        | There : forall n (c : arityCode n) (v : Vector.t t n) (i : Fin.t n),
                    path (Vector.nth v i) -> path (Node c v).

      Example node1 := Node Num [].
      Example children : Vector.t t 2 := [node1; Node Hole []].
      Example node2 := Node Arrow children.

      (* This example can also be typed simply as `path node`, but we type it this way
         to use it as a subath in the next example.
       *)
      Example here  : path (*node1*) (Vector.nth children Fin.F1) := Here _ _.
      Example there : path node2 := There _ children Fin.F1 here.

      Inductive direction : Type :=
      | Child : nat -> direction
      | PrevSibling : direction
      | NextSibling : direction
      | Parent : direction.

      Fixpoint move_in_path
               (node : t)
               (dir : direction)
               (the_path : path node)
        : option (path node) :=
        match node with
        | @Node num_children code children =>
          match the_path with
          | There _ _ i sub_path => move_in_path (Vector.nth children i) dir sub_path
          | Here _ _ =>
            match dir with
            | Child n =>
              match Fin.of_nat n num_children with
              | inleft fin_n =>
                  (* The problem:

                      The term "Here ?a@{n0:=n; n:=n0} ?t@{n0:=n; n:=n0}" has type
                      "path (Node ?a@{n0:=n; n:=n0} ?t@{n0:=n; n:=n0})" while it is expected to have type
                      "path (Vector.nth children fin_n)".

                      How can I convince Coq that `Vector.nth children fin_n`
                      has type `path (Node a t)`?
                    *)
                  let here : path (Vector.nth children fin_n) := Here _ _ in
                  let there : path node := There _ children fin_n here in
                    Some there
              | inright _ => None
              end
            | _ => None (* TODO handle other directions *)
            end
          end
        end.

    End Typ.
End Core.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a smart constructor for `Here` which does not have any constraint on the shape of the `t` value it is applied to:

```
 Definition Here' (v : t) : path v := match v return path v with
   | Node c vs => Here c vs
 end.
```

You can then write:

```
let here : path (Vector.nth children fin_n) := Here' _ in
```